# Is this sentence grammatical?

Tags: word-order

Below is a passage from a post on the internet where a user asked about a wifi problem.

> I am aware that the stronger/est antenna captures the bandwidth.  So, at friend's location and when connecting to public wifi, **I need a stronger antenna, it seems**.

I would like to ask about the sentence in bold in the passage. It seems like the sentence is upside down in its order with the part **"it seems"** placed at the end instead of at the beginning. That makes me feel like it might not be grammatical.

Comment: It's OK to add **it seems** as an afterthought in that way. People do that all the time—or so it seems. https://books.google.com/books?id=DVRMfbJNJ0MC&pg=PA156&dq=%22it+seems+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGx-uH0b_SAhVr6oMKHY1iBFM4jAEQ6AEIeDAQ#v=onepage&q=%22it%20seems%20the%22&f=false

Comment: Or this: https://books.google.com/books?id=bwLYeyiIpNIC&pg=PA49&dq=%22it+seems+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS3M_i0b_SAhUCSCYKHRLfDzI4oAEQ6AEIgAEwEg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20seems%20the%22&f=false

Comment: @TRomano Thank you for the comments and for the examples from real books. From your words - __"so it seems"__ is __"it seems so"__ also okay to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example has a few irregularities and doesn't sound like natural English, but putting "it seems" at the end is fine.  It's somewhat less *formal* that way, as if the sentence were spoken, rather than written, but since it's an informal topic it fits.

I think you are trying to say this:

> I understand that, the weaker the signal, the better the antenna needed to receive it properly.  So when at a friend's house with bad wifi, or connecting to a public wifi, I need a better antenna, it seems.

Although, my personal feeling is that this is more the fault of the wireless transmitter, and not your device's antenna.  If the signal is poor, it's usually because of incorrect (or insufficient) setup.

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer! I did get your help before as well. I appreciate it. And also thank you for the tip regarding the wifi problem, though I didn't write the post. :)

Comment: A little bit aside from the point, are both __"It seems I need a better antenna."__ and __"It seems that I need a better antenna."__ correct and holding the exact same meaning?